# Failing Direct3D test in WACK

Tags: microsoft-metro, mvvm-light, direct3d

I'm building a Windows Store app and I'm failing the App Certification Tool test for the Direct3D feature.  This is a general app with no specific calls to any graphics feature.

I've tried running the tests on two different machines so I don't think my problem is hardware specific.  More, I've tried testing a very basic app stripped of all UI controls except for a text block and I'm receiving the same error.  The machines are running RTM builds of Windows 8 and VS2012.

Essentially, I'm asking, what should I look at next to resolve this issue?

Thanks--

Comment: Are you saying that even a "Blank App" (with no change) fails that Direct3D test? If so, it has to be "environmental". It is likely that the machines you used have something in common that makes them both fail. Can you give more details about their configuration?

Comment: Thanks--the "basic app" I referred to was an unchanged app generated from the MVVMLight template.  I'll drop down to the Blank App template and try that next.  As for the machines, both are x86 with 4GB of RAM, though one is a VM and the other is running on it's own box.

Comment: Ok, I've tried creating a "Blank App" and running it through the WACK.  It goes through with no exceptions.  So I went back and returned to the basic MVVM Light app where I am still getting the Fail on the Direct3D test.  I've wired it up to report any unhandled exceptions and I'm not getting any nor is there any evidence of a crash from the subsequent launch event args...Very odd, since there's nothing apparent that should trigger such a problem.

Comment: Start from one end and try to get to the other one while running the WACK tests until you identify what exactly is causing the failure. So, you can start with the Blank App, copy'n'paste stuff from the MVVM Light app until the tests start failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing all available Windows Updates and try to run WACK again.

I had luck with this method on more than one machine. Apparently, pending updates cause the issue. install the updates, let the machine restart and finish the updating process. The issue should be gone after that.

Comment: Interesting--I thought I was up to date with all updates, especially given the big one last week, but I'll check again.  Can you tell me were you experiencing the Direct3D failure I mentioned?

Comment: @darrix Yup, exactly the same issue in many of my machines. However, I am running professional version and not RTM. I was working on an app with an `ItemsPage.xaml` and an `SplitPage.xaml` - simple thing. I started again with similar but blank app. Kept adding AdDuplex, Callisto step by step - all passed the certification. Then finally checked (and rechecked) my own app. It passed each and every time afterwards. Just check after update process is finished. It seems that 'reboot' is still a solution when it comes to Windows! :P

Comment: @darrix You're welcome! I see that the answer was accepted. Did it solve the issue? Just making sure that my preposition was correct!